# Get data from and manipulate Excel pivot table with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, pivot-table

I found a website about VB.net in combination with Excel pivot tables, but can't seem to find anything about getting the data and manipulating it. Is this possible?

Also, should I want this? I can programm both VBA and VB.net and want to create a nice GUI. I know VBA is a lot slower in processing the code, but I don't know how much time VB.net takes to get data from Excel.

Comment: It's certainly possible, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837611.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835831.aspx. However even Microsoft warn that "PivotTable report programming can be complex" in the first link there. In my experience it's more trouble than it's worth & you can achieve a result more easily (while keeping your code easier to understand for others) by using arrays or dictionaries with loops to collate your data. If you really want to do it read up on the object model, particularly the PivotFields, GetPivotData and GetData methods

Comment: I see the links are about VBA. I didn't know this was also applicable for VB.net. My data is coming from a real-time external source right into the pivot table. I don't like working with them in VBA but I don't see how I should do this with arrays

Comment: Since you're working with an Excel object you'll be using the Excel object model, there's no way round that. Some good examples here: https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/10/31/excel-pivot-tables-vbnet/. This describes getting Excel data into an .Net array https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/302094 - you can then work on the data fully in .Net.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful! What would be your preference, doing this in VB.net or in VBA? Since the data is in Excel I can imagine the processing is quicker with VBA, but since the general processing time of VB.net is way quicker I'm not sure which one to choose.

Comment: That depends on a lot of things but I suppose the primary consideration is whether you actually need the data in .Net for some purpose i.e are you building an application that uses the data from Excel to do other things (for instance plot locations on a map or create heatmap images from raw data), or are you just doing some data analysis that could happily live in a spreadsheet?

Comment: I get what you mean. Theoretically it can be done in a spreadsheet. I just wish to make a tool that executes as quick as possible and is handy for people that don't know anything about pc's or excel.